# How to use Variadic macros with fprintf

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor, variadic, variadic-macros

I am trying to print logs into a file by writing macros.
My macro looks like as shown below:

```
#define LOG(fmt,...){\
    FILE *F;\
    F = fopen("output.txt","a");\
    fprintf(F,fmt " %s %d",__VA_ARGS__,__FILE__,__LINE__);}
```

And I plan to call LOG in the following format:

```
LOG("values are : %d %d",num1,num2);
```

But when I compile I get the error

```
error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
     fprintf(F,fmt " %s %d",__VA_ARGS__,__FILE__,__LINE__);}
```

Can someone please explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: You know `__FILE__` is a `char[]`, not a `int`, right? And unrelated to your problem, I sincerely hope there is an `fclose()` somewhere in the **real** code, as otherwise you're leaking stream pointers like a sieve leaks rain water.

Comment: Check out this question. Works both in C and C++. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056411/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-printf-sprintf

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah sorry for the mistake there. There is fclose in the main program. In the hurry of copy paste missed it :-)

Comment: @NiklasHansson Thanks for the link. I shall check it out :)

Comment: I know this is potentially a dumb question, but I gotta ask. your toolchain supports variadic macros, right?

Comment: You probably can't afford to leak open file streams at the rate that code would do so.  You should check that the `fopen()` worked and close the file before you finish.  Or, more sensibly, you should call a function which handles stuff like caching the open file stream and manages the formatting more simply.

Comment: See also [C `#define` macro for debug printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1644898#1644898).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to wrap you macro into a do-while loop, so it will be handled with expressions correctly.

```
#define LOG( fmt , ... ) do{  }while(0)
```

Then you have to make sure that fopen() call succeeds and that you close the file after usage.

```
FILE* f = fopen( "output.txt" , "a" ) ;
if( !f )
    break ;    //break works because you are in a loop
fclose( f ) ;    //also flushes the stream
```

Then you include the print in the full macro.

```
#define LOG( fmt , ... )    \
        do{ \
            FILE* f = fopen( "output.txt" , "a" ) ; \
            if( !f )    \
                break ; \
            fprintf(f, fmt" %s %d\n",__VA_ARGS__,__FILE__,__LINE__);    \
            fclose( f ) ;   \
        }while( 0 )
```

The call is in the form:

```
LOG("values are : %d %d",4444,55555);
```

where you have to input at least one correct optional parameter, with the corresponding flag in the string.

Comment: I replaced __VA_ARGS__ with ##__VA_ARGS__ and it started working. Thanks :) 

I didnt understand why a loop is required. What happens when the loop isnt there?

Comment: @user1692342 You code was already correct( with some problems ), ##__VA_ARGS__ is a compiler extension.

Comment: @user1692342 The macro might not get handled correctly. Try a couple examples with and without do-while using if statements and you will see that the code will be broken in certain cases.

Comment: "##__VA_ARGS__ is a compiler extension." -- wow, good to know. I thought preprocessor behavior was more or less universal, and the environment probing was mostly there to enable platform-agnostic code for the compiler. When you say it's a compiler extension, do you mean that a preprocessed file containing `##a b c` becomes `a` during compilation, or were you using 'compiler' colloquially to mean the whole pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

```
#define LOG(fmt,...){\
    FILE *F;\
    F = fopen("output.txt","a");\
    fprintf(F,fmt " %d %d",__VA_ARGS__,__FILE__,__LINE__);}
```

Multiple issues

1. You never `fclose` F.
2. `__FILE__` is a string.
3. If you want to be able to call it without parameters `__VA_ARGS__` must go at the end...
4. ... or use this little hack:

   ```
   #define LOG(fmt,...){\
       FILE *F;\
       F = fopen("output.txt","a");\
       fprintf(F,fmt " %s %d", ##__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__,__LINE__);}
   ```

(**`##__VA_ARGS__` is a GCC extension** that removes the preceding comma if there are no args).

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26290648/675646) about "custom" printf-like functions.

Comment: I tried your code: THe following error occurs:

error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
 #define VA_ARG(...) , ##__VA_ARGS__

note: in expansion of macro ‘VA_ARG’
     fprintf(F,fmt " %s %d", VA_ARG(__VA_ARGS__),__FILE__,__LINE__);}

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot. That's an GCC extension. My bad. Also there was another mistake in the code I posted, fixed now.

Comment: It works If i have arguments passed :) If there are no arguments then junk values are printed :(